# How can I log lambda request id into AWS CloudWatch Api gateway log group with JSON format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have been working on a REST API which uses AWS API Gateway and lambda function.
Both Api gateway and lambda services are logging to CloudWatch service. I need to log lambda request id into AWS CloudWatch API gateway log group. (API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_{api_id}/{staging}).

I manage to get the lambda request id in text format but I want to log it in JSON format. In API gateway logs it is labeled as "AWS Integration Endpoint RequestId".
I have tried to find this property from the following link:
[List of Log Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference?cmpid=docs_apigateway_console)

Currently, "$context.requestId" is added into my CloudWatch logs. This is the request id for API Gateway. I need lambda request id in API Gateway logs. 
I have tried to log "$context.authorizer.principalId" but it is empty.

How can I get lambda request id from context object of API gateway request?

Answer (score 2):

From the [APIG reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference), it seems that you can use the `$context.awsEndpointRequestId` placeholder